# Getting Junk text. How to convert character array variable to LPARAM type?

Tags: c++, windows, char, sendmessage

I need to display the text on Text Box whatever data retrieve from files.

On push of particular button (**IDB_SHOW_BUTTON**) in windows application, I am doing as mentioned below:-

```
case IDB_SHOW_BUTTON:{  
   char buf[1000];  
   vReadFileFromHardisk(buf); //storing the read data of file to buffer
   SendMessage(editHwnd,WM_SETTEXT,NULL,(LPARAM)buf);//Due to this, I get junk text.
}
break;
```

I am reading data from file and storing it into buffer. I don't understand why i am getting junk text whenever I am clicking on the button.

When I change the **4th parameter** of **SendMessage** i.e. as mentioned below, I get the proper output on push of a particular button:-

```
SendMessage(editHwnd,WM_SETTEXT,NULL,(LPARAM)L"My First Edit Window");
```

Please let me know to how to display the proper text in case of storing data to **buf** and sending the same through **SendMessage**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using SendMessageA(..) instead. also its good to check compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the 'L' in the working example? You're passing a narrow character string into a function that expects Unicode.

You'll need to either

1. convert the text you've read in into Unicode - you can do this using [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx) amongst others; you'll need to know what encoding the input is, e.g. UTF-8
2. send the narrow form of the message, WM_SETTEXTA, to use the current system encoding for the data you've read
3. change your program settings from Unicode to Multi-byte (but don't do this)

I strongly recommend 1 and getting used to using Unicode (a.k.a. UTF-16) throughout your program.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. How to do using MultiByteToWideChar? Please show me one example. Thanks a a lot once again...

Comment: Thanks - and sorry about the example, I hadn't forgotten but I've been busy lately :-/ I'll come back and throw something together when I get a moment.